# Combine two functions for JQuery DatePicker BeforeShowDay

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, datepicker

How do I create a function that combines this first function that **disables specific days of the week**;

```
function disableweekdays(date) {
    var day = date.getDay();
    return [(day != 0 && day != 2 && day != 4 && day != 5), ""];  
}
```

with this second function that **disables special days of the year**;

```
function disablespecialdays(date){
    var array = ["12-25", "01-01"]
    var string = jQuery.datepicker.formatDate('mm-dd', date);
    return [ array.indexOf(string) == -1 ]
}
```

so that their results can be combined for the **beforeShowDay** in;

```
$("#myid").datepicker({
    beforeShowDay: disableweekdays,
    minDate: 0, 
    dateFormat: 'dd-MM-yy',
    inline: true,
    showOtherMonths: true,
    dayNamesMin: ['Sun', 'Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat'],
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can combine both conditions using the `&&` logical operator. it would need to pass all conditions to display the current date for the plugin. I used `Array#contains` rather that `Array#indexOf` as it's easier to understand.

```js
// mock jQuery.datepicker.formatDate
const pad = x => x < 10 ? '0' + x : x
const jQuery = { datepicker: { formatDate: (format, date) => `${pad(date.getMonth() + 1)}-${pad(date.getDate())}` }}

function disableDays(date) {
    var day = date.getDate();
    var datestamp = jQuery.datepicker.formatDate('mm-dd', date)
    var specialDays = ["12-25", "01-01"]
    
    return (
         day !== 0
      && day !== 2
      && day !== 4
      && day !== 5
      && !specialDays.includes(datestamp)
    )
}

// test the functions
console.log(
  disableDays(new Date()) // depends on the day and date
)

console.log(
  disableDays(new Date('12-25-2017')) // expect false if not sun, tue, thur, fri
)

console.log(
  disableDays(new Date('12-26-2017')) // expect true
)
```

```html
<script src="https://codepen.io/synthet1c/pen/KyQQmL.js"></script>
```

Comment: Works well after changing **date.getDate()** to **date.getDay()** and adding **[ ]** around **return**

Comment: Why do you need to wrap the result in an array? it should accept `true` or `false` if we are looking at the same plugin

Comment: You are right. @synthet1c. I was not using the plugin.